# Creating network dataset from template using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, arcgis-pro

I am using a script based on Esri's one, to create a network dataset from a template. I am using ArcGIS Pro 1.3. The problem is that the network dataset is not not created and I get no errors, so can't understand why there is no network dataset.

Here is my script:

```
    import arcpy
    import os
    import time
    
    #create name and path for new geodatabase with current date
    date_string = str((time.strftime("%Y%m%d")))
    gdb_name = "RoadNetwork"+"_"+date_string+".gdb"
    path = "O:/Projects/NetworkAnalyst"
    gdb_path = path + r"/" + gdb_name
    # Execute CreateFileGDB
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(path, gdb_name)    
    
    #creating new Network dataset from template
    try:
       #use template created before
       xml_template = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #'O:/Projects/NetworkAnalyst/Roads_Network_Template.xml' 

       #feature classes to be used for the network
       gates = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #'O:/Projects/NetworkAnalyst/RoadNetwork_20160411_old.gdb/Roadsegment/Roadsegment_Gates' 
       roads_update = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) #r'C:\Users\LidiaD\Documents\ArcGIS\Roads_FT_20160612.gdb\Roads_FT_Merged' 

       #create feature dataset within the geodatabase
       out_name = "RoadNetwork"
       sr = roads_update
       arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(gdb_path, out_name, sr)

       #copy new roads and turns from previous dataset into the new feature dataset
       path_fd = gdb_path + r"/" + "RoadNetwork"
       new_gates = path_fd + r"/" + 'Roadsegment_Gates'
       new_roads = path_fd  + r"/" 'Roadsegment'
       arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(gates, new_gates)
       arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(roads_update, new_roads)
    
       #Create the new network dataset in the output location using the template. This part does not work in ArcGIS Pro 1.3.
       arcpy.na.CreateNetworkDatasetFromTemplate(xml_template, path_fd)
    
       #Build the new network dataset 
       networkName = "Roadsegment_ND"
       arcpy.na.BuildNetwork(os.path.join(path_fd, networkName))
    
    except Exception as e:
       # If an error occurred, print line number and error message
       import traceback, sys
       tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
       print(("An error occurred on line %i" % tb.tb_lineno))
       print((str(e)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the reason your script isn't working as you haven't included any error messages.  The `try`/`except` is blocking those.

If you're running this from within ArcGIS Pro the reason you don't get any errors is because your script has `print` statements, and ArcGIS only outputs messages through `arcpy`.

I have added an intentional error into your script and run from ArcGIS Pro, and I get the following result:

[image]

These messages are output using `arcpy.AddMessage()`, `arcpy.AddWarning()`, and `arcpy.AddError()` in place of the `print`.

Changing the `print` statements to `arcpy.AddMessage()` and re-running in ArcGIS Pro I get:

[image]

You need to either changing your `print` to `arcpy.AddMessage()` or remove the `try`/`except`.  Removing the try and except will allow any errors to come through to the geoprocessing window and give useful information while testing.